# Error when publishing Infopath Forms to other env after modifying the URL / ListID and CT ID

Tags: 2010, infopath, deployment

I have a question regarding the Infopath forms in SharePoint 2010, just to explain the situation:
I've created a list infopath forms and I would like to use these forms in other environments like test, etc, because the forms are hard coupled to the list I cannot just install them to another envirment. Researching Google showed me that I can modify the manifest.xsf file in xsn with the new URL, ListID and the ContentTypeID, create a cab and publish that with the Infopath Designer.

I have done all of that, it seems to be correct BUT when I try to publish with Infopath Designer I get an error saying:

> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>   Value does not
>   fall within the expected range.

I've checked as well the logs and I see the following in there:

```
ConstructFromXsnFile failed with unhandled exception System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId..ctor(String id)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.DataAdapterListDataProvider.Parse(XPathNavigator dataAdapterNode, XPathNavigator serverConfigNode, XmlNamespaceManager solutionNamespaceManager, Solution solution)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.DataAdapter.CreateDataAdapter(XPathNavigator dataAdapterNode, XPathNavigator serverConfigNode, XmlNamespaceManager solutionNamespaceManager, Solution solution, CreateAdapterMode mode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.DataAdapters.Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.ISolutionComponent.Parse(XPathNavigator documentClassNode, XmlNamespaceManager solutionNamespaceManager, ConversionContext context)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.Solution.ParseManifest(ConversionContext context, XPathNavigator node)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.Solution.LoadFromXsn(ConversionContext context, SolutionCabinet solutionCabinet, SolutionIdentity solutionId)    
 at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.SolutionLifetime.Solution.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ConstructFromXsnFile>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
```

And

```
Deployment failed conversion, or design checker found fatal errors: An unexpected error has occurred while verifying the form template.
```

I did not change anything on the template, only the values for URL / List ID and ContentTypeID, 
 These parts that I have changed in manifest:

```
<xsf3:solutionDefinition>
   <xsf3:viewsExtension>
    <xsf3:viewExtension ref="Edit item"></xsf3:viewExtension>
    </xsf3:viewsExtension>
    <xsf3:baseUrl relativeUrlBase="http://sp2010/TestSite/ListItems/ListItem/"/>
 </xsf3:solutionDefinition>
```

And

```
<xsf:query>
        <xsf:sharepointListAdapterRW queryAllowed="yes" submitAllowed="yes" siteURL="../../" sharePointListID="{B03A676F-780D-49F7-B9CA-0FDD4FFB8CDR}" name="Main Data Connection" contentTypeID="0X0100068ECFE0863EFF45A9B7ECB118B5EFA700205EF8DA3DFCF34AB31EA5C2A6B923BG" relativeListUrl="../" version="dc19d1e732d326f4" queryOneItemOnly="yes">
```

Anyone did come across this issue?
And how do you resolve it?

Many resources explained about this approach so I suppose it should work now I would like to know why it doesn't work for me. Can anyone assist me?